# Unhandled Runtime Errorre: Referenceerror $ is not defined [jQuery in NextJs app]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript, next.js

### There could be several reasons for a JavaScript "Unhandled Runtime Error" to occur. Some common causes include:

- Syntax errors in the code: This can happen if there is a typo or incorrect syntax in the code.
- Reference errors: This can happen if a variable or function is not defined before it is used.
- Type errors: This can happen if a variable is used in a way that is not consistent with its data type.
- Unhandled exceptions: This can happen if an exception is thrown and not caught by a try-catch block.
- Unhandled promise rejection: This can happen if a promise is rejected and not handled with a .catch() block.

It's recommended to check the error message and the line number provided by the browser console and the code surrounding that line to understand the reason for the error.

## What was my case

### Reference error. What does reference error mean exactly?

#### Let's have a look then more details about of Reference error

> *A reference error in JavaScript occurs when a variable or function is used before it has been defined. This means that the JavaScript interpreter cannot find a reference to the variable or function in its current scope.*

For example, if you have a line of code that uses a variable called "x" but you haven't defined "x" anywhere in your code, JavaScript will throw a reference error.

It's also possible to have a reference error if you try to access a property or method of an object that doesn't exist.

The error message associated with a reference error typically includes the name of the variable or function that caused the error, and the line number in the code where the error occurred.

For example `console.log(x);` where x is not defined anywhere will throw a reference error.

It's important to make sure that all variables and functions used in your code are properly defined and initialized before they are used in order to avoid reference errors.

#### In my project I ware using jQuery with the Nextjs app. both libraries' design patterns were not the same and for this reason, we can't use as like other js libraries(moment, date, etc.)

> ## So, What's the way to use jQuery with the NextJs app?

### Here are the details

1. Next.js is a JavaScript framework for building server-rendered React applications. To use jQuery with a Next.js app, you will need to include the jQuery library in your project. You can either include it as a local file or reference it from a Content Delivery Network (CDN).
   Here is an example of how to include jQuery in your Next.js app using a CDN:
   In your JSX file, add the following script tag to include the jQuery library:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2. In your JavaScript code, you can now use jQuery as you normally would. Alternatively, you can use npm package manager to install jQuery and import it in your .js file as:

```
npm install jquery
```

then in your .js file:
import $ from 'jquery'

### If those solution doesn't solve your problem(Unhandled Runtime Errorre: Referenceerror $ is not defined), there is another method

#### Use Script from 'next/script'

```
import Script from 'next/script';
```

#### And now have a look at where we wrongly setup "next/script"

```
## strategy

<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/popper.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/jquery.sticky-sidebar.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/slick.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/custom.js" />
```

#### Try to understand the meaning of "strategy" and use exactly what you need.

Next Script has a total of four strategies

```
"lazyOnload" | "afterInteractive" | "beforeInteractive" | "worker"
```

The default setup is afterInteractive but when we have to use "lazyOnload", "beforeInteractive" and "worker"?

## At this point I also did the mistake.

### but the solution is very simpler

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script
```

#### You can have a look at both Script setups and try to match what's the difference between them.

```
## strategy

<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js" />
<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="./assets/js/popper.min.js" />
<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="./assets/js/jquery.sticky-sidebar.min.js" />
<Script strategy="beforeInteractive" src="./assets/js/slick.min.js" />
<Script strategy="lazyOnload" src="./assets/js/custom.js" />
```

@Wish you, Hope your issue will fix...

Comment: "*I should receive only Sunday*" doesn't make sense. The function returns only true or false. Runable snippets need to be javascript, not typescript.  Once the *date* object has been converted to a *Date* instance, the rest of the function can be simply `return !(date.getDay() % 6)`.

Comment: The javascript in the OP doesn't compile, it throws an error (export can't be the first identifier in a statement). Creating a *Date* that way will return the UTC date, so likely the day before for users with a negative offset (i.e. positive ECMAScript offset). It's also unnecessarily verbose.